# HTML Accordion - opening all rows at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

This very basic [accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion) works very nicely and you can open and close each row and leave more than one row open at the same time.

How can one provide a button action that will open ALL rows at the same time, as well as close all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleAll()">Toggle</button>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
function toggleAll(){
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var count = acc.length
    var open = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<count; i++){
            open+=1 ? acc[i].nextElementSibling.style.display=="block":0
            }
    for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        var panel = acc[i].nextElementSibling;
        if (open==count) {
          if(acc[i].classList.contains("active"))
            acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
          panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          if(!acc[i].classList.contains("active"))
            acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
          panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was not the one doing the downvote, but I tried this on the W3Schools console and also on Chrome and it did NOT work. Are you able to track what is going on.  Maybe publishing the whole code would be best.

Comment: This solution clothes the ones that are open and open the ones that are closed, which is different from clothing all/opening all, from any state you start.

Comment: Yes! It does work. Maybe you should change the name of the button from "Toggle" to "Open/Close All" which is a bit more descriptive and will be less confusing for people in the future. Somehow I cannot edit your solution.

Answer (score 1):

***Working Code !!!***

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
var len = panel.length;
var i, k;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}


function handleToggle() {
  var open = 0, close = 0;
  for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    panel[k].style.display === "block" ? open++ : close++;
  }
  if(open && close && (open !== len || close !== len)) {
    for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
      panel[k].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  if(open === len || close === len) {
    for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
      if (panel[k].style.display === "block") {
        panel[k].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        panel[k].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleToggle()">Toggle Accordian</button>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works very nicely, except for the way it interacts with the older code. Some of the highlight of the old rows are gone and the plus/minus signs indicating if they are open or not no longer work. Could you provide a full code that preserves the old functionality?

Comment: @paulo Sure..give me some time today will do that

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've changed the code to close and open all rows. Note this solution doesn't take into account the current state of any rows.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var btn = document.getElementById('toggle-all'); // store ref to button
var open = true;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

// add click event listener to new button
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');// select all headings
    open = !open

    // iterate over heading elements
    panels.forEach(panel => {
        const display = panel.nextElementSibling.style.display;// get current text of paragraph
        panel.classList.toggle('active');// toggle active class
        panel.nextElementSibling.style.display = open ? 'none' : 'block';// toggle paragraph display
    })
})
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id='toggle-all'>Toggle All</button>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this one opens all the rows that are closed and close all the ones that are open, which is different from - opening all at the same time and closing all at the same time.